# How to define an area for layout and controllers like adminhtml and frontend in magento2?

Tags: magento2

I want to create a separate area for vendor just like Adminhtml and frontend.

Is that possible??

Comment: vendor as in seller (sub-admin) or ?

Comment: yes as seller not sub-admin. Separate interface for seller other than frontend and admin panel.

Comment: what role is then your seller has if its not one of admin

Comment: separate entity like customer and admin.

Comment: Every  thing is possible but lot of works need

Comment: Yes possible, I want the way.

Comment: I found the way here, https://alankent.me/2014/07/20/playing-around-with-magento-2-areas/.